How to store data in a telgram bot in a fast way
I am making a telegram bot that requires to store data for a user
This could be around 1000 users.
Im using node.js
I tried to use SQl to store the data but its too slow and can take a second to find the user (which for what Im doing is way too long)
Is there a way to store it and get the data quickly
Sql -- too slow
JSON -- not secure, too slow

one second to find a user? Did you add an Index to your column fields in your 'WHERE' clause?

You can use MongoDB.
We used MongoDB when we built the T2E game on Telegram. It provided sufficient loading speed.
You can also use local variables to store the changed values ​​well. You don't need to store this variable for every change.
